# How do two users start/stop a service? eg: Tomcat

Tags: ubuntu, kill, tomcat

I found a big problem with sharing management of tomcat server.

Eg:
There are 2 Linux accounts (ua & ub) both in charge of start/stop certain tomcat server.

ua: Start tomcat server with generating a pid file.

ub: Try to stop the tomcat by `shutdown.sh -force`, however it does not work since ub can not kill the process started by ua.

Instead of sharing single Linux account, is there a good way to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make an account for the service . set up sudoers to grant ua ub ability of running as the service account . like this .

```
# /etc/sudoers
ua,ub ALL= (service-account) /usr/sbin/daemon-programme,/bin/kill
```

where service-account is the account name . then users can run this and vice versa .

```
ua $ sudo -u service-account /usr/bin/daemon-programme --pid-file /run/programme.pid
ub $ sudo -u service-account /bin/kill $(cat /run/programme.pid)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! From your explanation, I get clue of why many service like mysql create a dedicated account when installation.

Comment: I think it can be improved further. Like `sudo service mysql restart`, there is no need to explicitly set uid, but mysql server is run as mysql account. How to achieve that?